# Does graph G contain a 100-node clique as a subgraph? Is it in P?

Tags: np-complete

Although the clique problem is NP-complete, is this restricted version also considered to be NP-complete or is it actually in P?

I would imagine since you are still trying to solve the clique problem then this problem would still be NP-complete but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did you ask about $100$-cliques instead of $2$-cliques or $3$-cliques? Is it because $x^2$ and $x^3$ are polynomials, but you aren't sure if $x^{100}$ is a polynomial?

Comment: Just a different number (but still common) number I suppose.

Comment: So you think determining whether a graph contains a $3$-node clique might be an NP-complete problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerate all possible ways to make a 100 node subgraph. (If there are $n$ nodes, it can take $O(n^{100})$ time.) Check if it is complete. Clearly this is in P.

Comment: How is this in P? Enumerating all possible 100 node subgraphs would take non-poly wouldn't it?

Comment: It would take $O(n^{100})$ time, so still polynomial.

Comment: so you are just checking every possible 100 node subgraph for it being a clique and once we find one we stop? It would be np-complete if you had to search through the graph finding a clique though right?

Comment: @sanic If there is no 100-node clique, or if there is only one such clique and it's the last one we check,then we have to look at every 100-node subgraph. So what, the number of 100-node subgraphs is less than $n^{100}.$